# Export custom visualization into .pbiviz for PowerBI desktop import

Tags: powerbi

I know it's possible to create your custom visualization in Power BI Dev Tool and use it in PowerBI.com but is it possible to export a visualization created in Visual Studio into a .pbiviz file and import it in Power BI for Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .pbiviz file you create from the Power BI Dev Tools can be used in both the Power BI service and Power BI Desktop.  You might need to update your Power BI desktop build with the latest. Then you'll see the "..." icon in visualization pane and you can import any .pbiviz files you have.   https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop

We do not have the ability for Visual Studio (the GitHub project really) to generate a .pbiviz file.  Now a .pbiviz file is just a zip archive, so you might be able to create a gulp tasks that build compatible .pbiviz files right from a Visual Studio build.  We have this in our backlog, but we'd be really thankful  should you (or someone else) submit a PR with this capability to the Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals repro.

http://wwww.github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals

Comment: Is this feature still in the backlog?

Comment: Yes it is in our backlog.  Best way to track this feature is vote for it on  http://ideas.powerbi.com.  Here's the item for this ask: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11020722-export-visuals-form-visual-studio-to-pbiviz

Answer (score 2):

In VSCode, this action can be performed by typing the following into the integrated terminal

```
pbiviz package
```

You can find the .pbiviz file in the dist folder once compiling is complete.